# Unit Test Slick Query without extra DB setup

Tags: database, scala, unit-testing, slick

How do I unit-test my Slick queries without setting up another Database driver for my query tests?

Some good resources should be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am not aware of any public examples of this. Probably someone should write an activator template for that. There are several different way to go though. Which one are you looking for exactly? What do you mean by "without setting up another Database driver"?

Comment: There is something testing related here: https://coderwall.com/p/a2vnxg  But is not exactly what you are looking for and uses `threadLocalSession` which is discouraged and Slick 1 api (now called `dynamicSession`).

Comment: I have a github project I used to figure this out. Technically you have to write a new driver, but there are not-so-terrible ways to do it. https://github.com/drstevens/slick-testing

Comment: also posted here: https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/scalaquery/3e01f57c-e5d2-4b08-93d7-63d243711492%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

Comment: I'd really like a definition for "Unit Test Slick Query", eg. do you mean the generated query? Do you mean the executed query? These two are very very different things.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I have seen some googled example that set up another test database (driver) alongside the database driver being used by the code. I do not really want to go down the same route. I think I am testing (more like) generated query, which is the Slick/Scala-ish code and not the "select * from..." kind of query.